# Electron: add redux devtools

Tags: javascript, electron

Running into an issue adding Redux Devtools to my Electron instance.

Followed instructions [here](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/devtools-extension), added the extension to my Chrome instance, then tried to call `addDevToolsExtension` in my electron instance:

```
const electron = require('electron');
const app = electron.app;
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;

const path = require('path');
const os = require('os');
const isDev = require('electron-is-dev');

let mainWindow;

function createWindow() {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width: 900, height: 680 });
    mainWindow.loadURL(isDev ? 'http://localhost:3000' : `file://${ path.join(__dirname, '../build/index.html') }` );
    mainWindow.addDevToolsExtension(
        path.join(os.homedir(), '/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd/2.17.0_0')
    );
    if (isDev) {
        mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
    }
    mainWindow.on('closed', () => { mainWindow = null } );
}

app.on('ready', createWindow);

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit();
    }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
    if (mainWindow === null) {
        createWindow();
    }
})
```

However, I'm still getting an error that `a Javascript error occurred in the main process` and that it can't find the `addDevToolsExtension` method on `mainWindow`. I know that "the BrowserWindow.addDevToolsExtension API cannot be called before the ready event of the app module is emitted," as noted on the Electron page, but this call should be after `ready` is called since the file waits for the `ready` event to execute `createWindow`, no?

Comment: You should use static method `BrowserWindow.addDevtoolsExtension`.

Comment: this did it. thanks!